# Java code that compiles in older Oracle versions gives compile error in Oracle 12.2

Tags: java, oracle, compiler-errors

A small piece of Java code that we've been using since Oracle 9 gives a compile error in Oracle 12.2.

(It looks like the code originated here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584)

Has something changed in 12.2 so that we need to change our Java code or some new permission that needs to be granted?

Edit: Commenting out the line with the SQL insert code results in correct compilation. Maybe that syntax is no longer available?

```
create or replace and compile java source named "DirList"
as
   import java.io.*;
   import java.sql.*;
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

   public class ChpDirList{

      public static void getList(String directory)
                         throws SQLException {

         File path = new File( directory );
         String[] list = path.list();
         String element;

         for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

            element = list[i];

            String fpath=directory+"/"+list[i];
            File f = new File(fpath);
            long   len;

            String ftype;

            if (f.isFile()) {

               len   = f.length();
               ftype = "F";

            } else {

              len   = 0;
              ftype = "D";
           }

           #sql { INSERT INTO NGM_DIR_LIST (file_name, file_length, file_type, file_modified)
                  VALUES (:element, :len, :ftype, null) };
       }
      }
   }
/
```

The error message:

```
Compilation errors for JAVA SOURCE NGM42.DIRLIST

#13#10Error: An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_121-ea). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.

Line: 0

#13#10Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.<init>(JCDiagnostic.java:412)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic$Factory.create(JCDiagnostic.java:238)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic$Factory.error(JCDiagnostic.java:103)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractLog.error(AbstractLog.java:117)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.lexError(JavaTokenizer.java:136)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.nextToken(Scanner.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.nextToken(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.accept(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.methodDeclaratorRest(JavacParser.java:3586)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3532)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBody(JavacParser.java:3436)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3285)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceOrEnumDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3226)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.typeDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3215)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseCompilationUnit(JavacParser.java:3155)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:676)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:1037)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:926)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:890)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at oracle.aurora.jdkcompiler.JdkDriver.compile(JdkDriver.java:572)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler.doCompile(Compiler.java:663)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler.access$000(Compiler.java:57)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:319)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Line: 0

#13#10Error: at oracle.aurora.rdbms.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:317)

Line: 0
```

Comment: Try compiling it with the version of Java that comes with the database. As far as I recall, Oracle still only supports Java 1.5.

Comment: Thanks, I'm compiling it inside the database. It maybe that Oracle's support for Java 8 might be an issue:

Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1) provides support for Java 8

Comment: This compiles fine on Oracle 12.1, can you check the Java version it should be 1.6 `SELECT  dbms_java.get_ojvm_property(PROPSTRING=>'java.version') FROM dual;`

Comment: Yes, we've been using this code for a long time. Testing in 12.2 now but ran into this compilation problem.  Java version = 1.8.0_121

Comment: The one thing that leaps out is `Date`. Java8 implements a new set of Date libraries. But don't know whether that affects `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and it's not clear from your posted code how you use that package anyway.

Comment: @Rene A wild guess, you have an insert script with column `ile_type` are you sure that isn't a typo?

Comment: Well spotted. That f must have been lost while formatting my code a bit here on this forum.  The column name is file_type in the original code. Will correct my question.

Comment: Problem can be traced back to the #SQL line. Commenting out that line and the code compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that server-side SQLJ is no longer supported in Oracle 12.2. A little rewrite of the code did the trick.

```
create or replace and compile java source named "DirList" as

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ChpDirList {

 public static void getList(String directory)
 throws SQLException {

  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
  String sql = "INSERT INTO NGM_DIR_LIST (file_name, file_length, file_type) values (?,?,?)";

  File path = new File(directory);
  String[] list = path.list();
  String element;

  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

   element = list[i];


   String fpath = directory + "/" + list[i];

   File f = new File(fpath);

   long len;

   String ftype;


   if (f.isFile()) {

    len = f.length();
    ftype = "F";

   } else {

    len = 0;
    ftype = "D";
   }

   PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pstmt.setString(1, element);
   pstmt.setLong(2, len);
   pstmt.setString(3, ftype);

   pstmt.executeUpdate();
   pstmt.close();
  }
 }
}
```